# Two users run a transaction at the same time?

Tags: mysql

If I perform a transaction like:

- Find a user who id is 10 and flag is 0.
- Flag user.

For instance:

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE users SET flag = 1 WHERE id = 10 AND flag = 0;
COMMIT;
```

What happens when two people browsing a website run this query at the same time?

Will the "second" user fail (not yield any result as user id 10 flag is set)? How is a "second" user defined if both set query off at same time?

Comment: Both users will execute the query, which one happens first is undefined. The first to execute will get back 1 rows updated, the second 0 rows.

Comment: I think unpredictable would be a better term than undefined, otherwise I agree with Boris - they will run one after the other, and the 2-nd one will see 0 rows with flag=0.

Comment: I guess the point is that the premise is flawed - "_What happens when two people ...run this query at the same time?_". They can't.